# Drupal 8 add ajax form element after ajax callback

Tags: ajax, forms, drupal, drupal-8

I am building a drupal form with multiple ajax enabled form elements.

I have one select list that does an ajax callback after change. The problem is that it adds a new select list to the page, which is also ajax enabled. This does not seem to work, which seems logical to me because the ajax is actually bundled an added to the page so it is lost in the replacecommand.

Is there anyone experienced with this, and does anyone have a solution ?

This is my code

```
  /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $form['city'] = [
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => $this->t('Station'),
            '#description' => $this->t('City'),
            '#options' => array(
                'Aalst' => $this->t('Aalst'),
                'Brussel' => $this->t('Brussel'),
                'Hasselt' => $this->t('Hasselt'),
                'Leuven' => $this->t('Leuven'),
            ),
            '#ajax' => [
                'callback' => array($this, 'extendFormAjax'),
                'event' => 'change',
                'progress' => array(
                    'type' => 'throbber',
                    'message' => t('Choose City'),
                ),
            ],
            '#suffix' => '<div id="extended-form"></div>',
        ];

        $form['submit'] = [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Submit'),
        ];

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Ajax callback to validate the email field.
     */
    public function extendFormAjax(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $parking = [
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => $this->t('Parking'),
            '#description' => $this->t('Parking'),
            '#options' => [
                'P1' => $this->t('P1'),
                'P2' => $this->t('P2'),
            ],
            '#ajax' => [
                'callback' => array($this, 'extendFormAjax'),
                'event' => 'change',
                'progress' => array(
                    'type' => 'throbber',
                    'message' => t('Choose parking'),
                ),
            ],
        ];

        $response = new AjaxResponse();
        $response->addCommand(new InsertCommand('#extended-form', $parking));

        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: I am experiencing this same problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and i resolved it by adding the element in buildForm and adding a wrapper for it and sending the form element via `HtmlCommand`

```
  /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    $form['city'] = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => $this->t('Station'),
        '#description' => $this->t('City'),
        '#options' => array(
            'Aalst' => $this->t('Aalst'),
            'Brussel' => $this->t('Brussel'),
            'Hasselt' => $this->t('Hasselt'),
            'Leuven' => $this->t('Leuven'),
        ),
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => array($this, 'extendFormAjax'),
            'event' => 'change',
            'progress' => array(
                'type' => 'throbber',
                'message' => t('Choose City'),
            ),
        ],
    ];
     $form['parking'] = [
        '#prefix' => '<div id="extended-form">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => $this->t('Parking'),
        '#description' => $this->t('Parking'),
        '#options' => [
            'P1' => $this->t('P1'),
            'P2' => $this->t('P2'),
        ],
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => array($this, 'extendFormAjax'),
            'event' => 'change',
            'progress' => array(
                'type' => 'throbber',
                'message' => t('Choose parking'),
            ),
        ],
    ];

    $form['submit'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
}

/**
 * Ajax callback to validate the email field.
 */
public function extendFormAjax(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
    $parking = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => $this->t('Parking'),
        '#description' => $this->t('Parking'),
        '#options' => [
            'P1' => $this->t('P1'),
            'P2' => $this->t('P2'),
        ],
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => array($this, 'extendFormAjax'),
            'event' => 'change',
            'progress' => array(
                'type' => 'throbber',
                'message' => t('Choose parking'),
            ),
        ],
    ];

    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#extended-form', $parking));

    return $response;
}
```

Try it like this. I have not tested the code.

Comment: hi @razeem, I am working on 8.7.7, only your solution is RIGHT. But there is one small miss, what solution you provided, just one edit needed.

Comment: There is an issue with this reply, the second select doesnt work any more since its not a part of form, you are just adding as html...the on change also doesnt work...any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Try call somewhere in JS `Drupal.attachBehaviors();`

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue and resolved it by this way :
For each element  which were populated by Ajax, I add the property "#validated" => true and in the callback, the returned field must have the same attributes (id, name) that the original field :

```
$form['example_field'] = array(
        '#type'         => 'select',
        '#required'     => FALSE,
        '#options'      => getDynamicOptions(),
        '#prefix'       => '<div id="etablissement-type-wrapper">',
        '#suffix'       => '</div>',
        '#attributes'   => [
            'data-drupal-selector'  =>  "edit-example",
            'id'    =>  "edit-example",
            'name'  =>  "example",
        ],
        '#validated' => TRUE,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add ajax elements in buildForm methods and rebuild form. Something like this:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $no_js_use = FALSE) {

    // We want to deal with hierarchical form values.
    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;

    $form['step'] = [
      '#type' => 'value',
      '#value' => !empty($form_state->getValue('step')) ? $form_state->getValue('step') : 1,
    ];

    switch ($form['step']['#value']) {
      case 1:
        $limit_validation_errors = [['step']];
        $form['step1'] = [
          '#type' => 'fieldset',
          '#title' => $this->t('Step 1: Personal details'),
        ];
        $form['step1']['name'] = [
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => $this->t('Your name'),
          '#default_value' => $form_state->hasValue(['step1', 'name']) ? $form_state->getValue(['step1', 'name']) : '',
          '#required' => TRUE,
        ];
        break;
      case 2:
        $limit_validation_errors = [['step'], ['step1']];
        $form['step1'] = [
          '#type' => 'value',
          '#value' => $form_state->getValue('step1'),
        ];
        $form['step2'] = [
          '#type' => 'fieldset',
          '#title' => t('Step 2: Street address info'),
        ];
        $form['step2']['address'] = [
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => $this->t('Your street address'),
          '#default_value' => $form_state->hasValue(['step2', 'address']) ? $form_state->getValue(['step2', 'address']) : '',
          '#required' => TRUE,
        ];
        break;
      case 3:
        $limit_validation_errors = [['step'], ['step1'], ['step2']];
        $form['step1'] = [
          '#type' => 'value',
          '#value' => $form_state->getValue('step1'),
        ];
        $form['step2'] = [
          '#type' => 'value',
          '#value' => $form_state->getValue('step2'),
        ];
        $form['step3'] = [
          '#type' => 'fieldset',
          '#title' => $this->t('Step 3: City info'),
        ];
        $form['step3']['city'] = [
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => $this->t('Your city'),
          '#default_value' => $form_state->hasValue(['step3', 'city']) ? $form_state->getValue(['step3', 'city']) : '',
          '#required' => TRUE,
        ];
        break;
    }

    $form['actions'] = ['#type' => 'actions'];
    if ($form['step']['#value'] > 1) {
      $form['actions']['prev'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Previous step'),
        '#limit_validation_errors' => $limit_validation_errors,
        '#submit' => ['::prevSubmit'],
        '#ajax' => [
          'wrapper' => 'ajax-example-wizard-wrapper',
          'callback' => '::prompt',
        ],
      ];
    }
    if ($form['step']['#value'] != 3) {
      $form['actions']['next'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Next step'),
        '#submit' => ['::nextSubmit'],
        '#ajax' => [
          'wrapper' => 'ajax-example-wizard-wrapper',
          'callback' => '::prompt',
        ],
      ];
    }
    if ($form['step']['#value'] == 3) {
      $form['actions']['submit'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t("Submit your information"),
      ];
    }

    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="ajax-example-wizard-wrapper">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    return $form;
  }

  public function prompt(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form;
  }

  public function nextSubmit(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_state->setValue('step', $form_state->getValue('step') + 1);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
    return $form;
  }

  public function prevSubmit(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_state->setValue('step', $form_state->getValue('step') - 1);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
    return $form;
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $messenger = \Drupal::messenger();
    $messenger->addMessage($this->t('Your information has been submitted:'));
  }
```