# How to switch between textfield and dropdown when they are both dependent on a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, drupal, drupal-8

I have a dropdown with countries, and I want to add a dependent dropdown or `textfield` with Ajax according to the selected value in the main dropdown.

***Case 1***
For example, if the user selects the **United States(US)** or **Canada(CA)**, the Ajax should fire and add a dependent dropdown.

If the **US**
Dropdown

- New York
- New Jersey
- California
- And more options

If **CA**
Dropdown

- Ontario
- Manitoba
- Quebec
- And more options

The select(dependent dropdown) has to be required.

***Case 2***
If the user selects any other country, the Ajax should fire and add a dependent `textfield`

If any country but not **US** nor **CA**

- Textfield

The `textfield` has to be required too.

I tried the options [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/ajax-forms#ajax_callback_render_array)

***Using the AJAX command option***

```
//This is my main select
$form['country'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $this->t(‘Select Country'),
  '#options' => [
    ‘US’ => t(‘United State’),
    'CA' => t('Canada’),
    ‘BR’ => t(‘Brazil’),
    ‘CO’ => t(‘Colombia’),
  ],
  '#default_value' => 'US',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#empty_option' => $this->t('Please select'),
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => [$this, 'addDependentField’],
    'event' => 'change',
    'wrapper' => 'output-dependent’, // This element is updated with this AJAX callback.
    'progress' => [
      'type' => 'throbber',
      'message' => $this->t('Verifying entry...'),
    ],
  ]
];

// Here I want to add a select or textfield. This dependes on the value from the main select above
$form[‘dependent_field’] = [
  '#title' => $this->t('State/Province'),
  '#prefix' => '<div id=“dependent-field”>’,
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
];

public function addDependentField(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $selectedValue = $form_state->getValue('country');

  switch ($selectedValue) {
    case 'US':
      $elem = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => [
          'NY' => t('New York'),
          'CA' => t('California'),
          'NJ' => t('New Jersey'),
          'WA' => t('Washington'),
        ],
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#attributes' => [
          'id' => ['edit-output'],
        ],
      ];
      break;

    case 'CA':
      $elem = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => [
          'ON' => t('Ontario'),
          'PE' => t('Prince Edward Island'),
          'QC' => t('Quebec'),
        ],
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#attributes' => [
          'id' => ['edit-output'],
        ],
      ];
      break;

    default:
      $elem = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#size' => '60',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#attributes' => [
          'id' => ['edit-output'],
        ],
      ];
      break;
  }

  $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
  $renderedField = $renderer->render($elem);

  // Create the AjaxResponse.
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#edit-output-2', $renderedField));

  // Return the AjaxResponse object.
  return $response;
}
```

This works only the first time, then stops working, I think it is because the fields’ types are different.

***Using the render array option***
I just changed all code after `switch` for the code below

```
return $form['dependent_field'] = $elem;
```

And it has the same behavior, it works only the first time then stops working.

**I also tried**

- This to update [multiple times](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225083/how-to-update-multiple-fields-using-ajax)
- Replace [more than one element form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8529/is-it-possible-to-replace-more-than-one-form-element-wrappers-triggered-by-onl/8530#8530)
- Drupal 8 [add ajax form element after ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425020/drupal-8-add-ajax-form-element-after-ajax-callback)

And also I found the same bad behavior after trying those answers, I still think it might be because one field is `dropdown`, and the other is `texfield`` because I want to update it over the same field with different types.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a specific AJAX for it.
You can use Form API **'#states'**

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code to do ajax request.
This will get the list  of states for the country selected

```
$('#countries').change(function(){
   $.get("url/"+country,function(data,status){
       various countries = JSON.parse(data);
        for(var i = 0; i<countries.length; i++){
             document.getElementById().innerHTML += "<option>"+countries[i].state+"</option>";
            //here you can add the form field you wish to.
        }
    }
});
```